# How do I change the category permalink structure?

Tags: categories, permalinks

I've been trying to figure this out for ages. Please help.

I want my category pages to default to

www.teacherdavid.co.uk/blog/category

However my category pages default to

www.teacherdavid.co.uk/categories

**live example:**

https://www.teacherdavid.co.uk/interviews/

I can access the category pages at

www.teacherdavid.co.uk/blog/category

however this is not the where you are taken to when select to view a category page in the side bar on my blog page for example:

https://www.teacherdavid.co.uk/blog

I've tried to set the permalink structure for the category pages with no luck.

I should probably mentioned that I've removed the word "category" from my permalink structure using a plugin and my current post permalink structure is

/blog/%category%/%postname%/

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Admin panel, Under Settings -> Permalinks, you need to update Categtory Base as well.

For example, using "blog" as your category base would make your category links like `https://www.teacherdavid.co.uk/blog/%category%/%postname%/` If you leave these blank the defaults will be used.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much!  This worked well, however, now my posts are not working. The permalinks are correct but it's saying "nothing found" for example: 

https://www.teacherdavid.co.uk/interviews/become-good-at-language-learning/

Can you help?

Comment: Seems as though the problem was that I had "blog" as the category base and also in the post permalink structure.

Comment: So all issues been fixed or still getting errors after permalinks update?

Comment: @DavidMansaray if fixed, check author answer as CHOSEN.

Comment: @CSabhar yes All fixed, but it seems that I can't have 

that category permalink structure as 

domain.com/blog/%category%

and the post permalink structure  as

domain.com/blog/%category%/%postname%/

Any idea how to have both?

Comment: @DavidMansaray there is no need to add blog prefix on post permalinks structure only domain.com/%category%/%postname%/ will suffice, as when category is added in url system will automatically pickup blog as category base from settings. And obviously you don’t want to add blog into url when category name is not added into URL.